# Mysterious interface?

Tags: usb, dvd

I took apart my external DVD-RAM drive, and found that it was a normal desktop drive inside a caddy, with an interconnect board screwed on. But I haven't been able to find out what the interface on it was (see photos). Does anyone know?
Thanks,
Depths <3
P.S. The drive in question is a PBDS DS-8W1P 09C.
[photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3t9x.jpg) [photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlm3x.jpg)

Comment: Your photos are super blurry. Still, it seems like the typical SATA to me.

Comment: @Tom Yan it's an edge connector, 50 pin, 25 on each side, bigger than your standard sata connector, big ol' piece of plastic in the middle of the male connector. A few ppl say it may be eIDE, but I highly doubt that, cause ide is 44 pins.

Comment: Yeah, in-focus would be a whole lot better. Cropping tighter from further away would still give far more detail than what you have there.

Comment: One of these? http://www.scsi.solutions/index.php?page=scsi

Comment: 50 pins sounds like SCSI-2.

Answer (score 4):

This is *not* a desktop drive. It’s a laptop drive.

The connector is a “Slim Optical IDE” connector. There doesn’t appear to be any authoritative information available. You can find plenty of adapters though, to both SATA and 40-pin IDE.

I found a [Newegg offer for Dell replacement drives](https://www.newegg.ca/p/0XE-0080-008A0) (the drive in the question appears to be a Dell OEM drive). If we take a look at some of their pictures, this is a 1:1 match:

[image: connector comparison]

Comment: bruh, i have a desktop that .has that form factor of ODD

Comment: Your point being? This is a laptop drive, “slimline”. Desktop optical drives are 5.25″. Sure, some cases may have slots for slimline drives, but they’re rare. There’s mounting adapters, too, of course. It’s still a laptop drive.

Comment: My Dell Optiplex 755 has that type of odd, but it's sata instead of ide